# Django CORS allowing requests from non-allowed origin

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, cors, django-cors-headers

I have Django CORS running with an allowed origin list that looks like this:

```py
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
]
```

Yet if I request this using Python's `requests` library in my terminal it still allows the request.  I've even tried only allowing requests from `https://google.com`, but it still allows me to use my API.

Why is this? (I'm still new to Django, so sorry if this is a bad question)

Here are some other settings

Installed apps:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # internal
    'my_app1',
    'my_app2',
    'my_app3',
    # third party
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'debug_toolbar',
]
```

Middleware:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: what does requests library have to do with CORS ->https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From mozilla CORS [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses
> additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application
> running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different
> origin.

It is browser mechanism and has nothing to do with API protection in sense you are misinterpreting it

Comment: To be exact, this means `requests` (or other HTTP libraries) don't care about CORS headers. Only (compliant) browsers do.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Is there any equivalent of this for stopping users from using my API outside of my website?

Comment: It depends on how do you consume following API, you could ask question with details on what you are trying to achieve to get proper answer